# mysterious "command not found" when using source command in Linux

Tags: linux

I am using Fedora.  When I issue:

```
-bash-3.2$ source na-profile.conf
```

I get:

```
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
```

The na-profile.conf file looks like:

```
KEYTAB=server02 export KEYTAB;
ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/xxxx/11.2.0.1/yyyyy; export ORACLE_HOME;
TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin; export TNS_ADMIN;
PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

There are no extra lines or spaces in the file.

Comment: Check for Windows line endings in your script...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `;` in between to use two commands in a line:

```
KEYTAB=server02; export KEYTAB;
               ^
```

`source` is loading the contents of your `na-profile.conf` and does not know how to handle this line, hence the error.

Comment: Still am getting same output

Comment: Strange. What about sourcing the first line, then the second and so on, so you see where is the problem?